# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Magento 2 Multi Store

Tags: magento2.1, multistore

I have a website with magento 2 and I have create the multi-store on it everything is working fine but there are some issue on the new store.

links: 
old store: https://www.specopmfg.com
new store: http://blackskyrifleworks.com

New store showing these issues:-
[console showing these issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0lzK.png)

Also not loading the product media or any other media from the default store.

Anybody can help me to get out from it ?

Thanks In advance.
Mustak

Comment: All of the URLs in those error messages seem to belong to your old domain. Looks like you forgot to change some option/setting when moving your store from the old to the new domain, so that the system creates a wrong basis URL.

Comment: no man ,https://www.specopmfg.com this is the default store .i think you understand wrong .these two domains are working on the same magento setup ,I have created multistore with http://blackskyrifleworks.com domain with uses the file of https://www.specopmfg.com store. understood

Comment: Okay, but still the second store should rather load all assets from its own domain. Go check the Base URL settings for that new “site” you created in the magento backend.

Comment: the base url is specopmfg.com,is this okay bcause its a main store ?

Comment: Your second store has its own configuration.

Comment: this is showing only main store ,where to change for second store ?
is this will get the js and all media from the main store ?

Comment: Did you set this up as two _websites_ in magento, or just two stores?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mwbk20
check this screenshot here already setup the base url

Comment: no i have just set two stores not two website.http://prntscr.com/mwbl7y